# Is there a difference between "on the internet" and "online"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I just got feedback from someone on a piece of my writing. He marked "**on the internet**" as confusing, compared to the term "**online**".

However, I felt that both work the same. Is there really a difference between **on the internet** and **online**? If so, when should you use them respectively?

For the record, I wrote, "*I learned to code from the resources on the internet.*"

Comment: A nuclear reactor is said to be *online* if it is "up" and generating electricity.  A hubcap stamping machine is *online* if it is productively making hubcaps.

Comment: By the way, did you really mean to write "respectfully"?

Comment: @MichaelKay You are right, that should be "respectively". Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically speaking, yes, there is a difference.  ***Online*** refers to a remote connection to most any computer network or service whereas ***on the internet*** refers specifically to the publicly accessible network that got its start as a US defense department project known as [ARPANET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPANET) (along with other projects, to be fair).

In the past, there were services such as [CompuServe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompuServe), [America OnLine (AOL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL), and [FidoNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FidoNet) as well as private services -- in the late '80s, I was the system manager of a company where *[timesharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-sharing)* was a significant part of their income.  (These days, the same concept -- storing your data and using programs on someone else's computer via a remote connection is called *the cloud*.)

So, yes, back in the day, you could go ***online*** to CompuServe or AOL or a Fido (or other) [BBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_board_system) without being connected to the internet.  Even today, there are systems and networks you can connect to via a phone line or other means without being connected to the internet.  (Note that internal networks, whether or not connected to the larger, external internet are called *[intranets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet)*.)

Note also that ***online*** has other meanings.  The Oxford Living Dictionaries includes this adverbial definition:

> ***[online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/online)***
>
> **ADVERB**
>
> In or into operation or existence.
>
> *‘the new power plant will go online this month’*
> *‘the company has additional production capacity coming online later this year’*

That said, if you were speaking to anyone other than an old, pedantic, computer history nerd like me, the assumption would be that ***online*** means the same thing as ***on the internet*** (primarily because most people have no idea that there is any other way to go online.)

In your specific situation, either option would be fine but, contrary to what your friend said, your use of ***on the internet*** is actually less ambiguous than their suggestion of ***online***.